# How does Tomcat inject the JNDI component-local context?

Tags: java, tomcat, jndi

In Tomcat, you can specify resources (JDBC connection, Javax mail sessions, etc.) in context.xml, reference them in web.xml, and then load them in Java like so:

```
Context ctx = new InitialContext();
DataSource dataSource = (DataSource)ctx.lookup("java:/comp/env/jdbc/myDB");
```

I'm interested in what magical voo doo is going on here! I would have expected the need to inject the `InitialContext` constructor with a hashtable or some other object, thereby injecting it with everything defined in context.xml and web.xml. But it's a no-arg constructor!!!

So I ask: what does Tomcat do to fill in the "missing link" between the 2 XML files and the `InitialContext` no-arg constructor so that the `DataSource` is magically available from the `ctx` instance? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This may help you understand the voodoo magic behind how the InitialContext constructor works without any parameters: http://www.tugay.biz/2016/07/extending-hello-jndi-example.html

Answer (score 11):

There are several parts to the magic voodoo as you describe it.

First of all early in the startup process Tomcat calls:

```
System.setProperty(javax.naming.Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
        "org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory");
```

This tells the JVM to use Tomcat's own factory for creating instances of InitialContext.

The second part is based around the fact that each web application has its own class loader and that all user code executes with that class loader set as the thread context class loader. Therefore, when a new InitialContext is created, Tomcat can look at the thread context class loader to determine which web application is making the request.

From there it is a simple process to hook up the new InitialContext object wth the right set of JNDI resources for the current application.

Comment: "it is a simple process"  - everything is simple once one understands it :-)

Comment: Can you tell me what value Tomcat will use for Context.PROVIDER_URL?

Answer (score 7):

At startup tomcat reads `context.xml` and creates all the resources defined there, and registers them with it's JNDI context. The code the you have posted is just the way to get those resources.

In `web.xml` (which is read when the web app is being deployed), the resources defined are not brand new. These are local to the web application, but will point to the resources defined in `context.xml`. The purpose of this is so that the Java code in your web app would be looking up the server resources indirectly.

Comment: Thanks @Bhesh Gurung (+1) - what classes/methods would Tomcat be using to register the resources (defined in context.xml) with its own JNDI context? How would this happen? What might it look like (code-wise)? Thanks again!

Comment: I am not sure what classes tomcat uses, for that one would have to dig into the tomcat's source code. But that's what you are planning then I think it would helpful to get the concept of [JNDI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/overview/index.html) first.

Comment: If you find the source then the main class is `org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap`.

Answer (score 4):

According to the Tomcat [documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html):

> The InitialContext is configured as a web application is initially
>   deployed, and is made available to web application components (for
>   read-only access).

If I had to guess, they just read the static location of your config files(`$CATALINA_BASE/conf/server.xml` etc) and provide it for each web application as they're deployed. The documentation also covers in detail each type of entry for each file and how each are treated.

Looking at the source code for [IntialContext.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/javax/naming/InitialContext.java) your hunch about a HashTable is correct, it does have a constructor for one and appears to store entries in a HashTable, myProps.

Comment: Thanks @MagicMan (+1) - please see my question under Bhesh Gurung's answer - I have the same followup question for you! Thanks again!

Comment: It uses various factory classes to instantiate your resource entries. For datasources it would be [BasicDataSourceFactory.java](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/apache/commons/dbcp/BasicDataSourceFactory.java.html) During Tomcat's startup it takes your arguments from context.xml and pairs them to the correct Factory. You can also create your own custom [Bean Factories](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html#Adding_Custom_Resource_Factories) if you have specific resource needs Tomcat doesn't provide by default.

Comment: Thanks again @MagicMan but I still don't think I'm explaining exactly what I'm looking for.  I now understand that Tomcat has parsers that read `context.xml` and match the resource entries to the correct factory. But how do those resource entires get mapped/injected/associated with my call to `new InitialContext()`? In other words, what is `InitialContext()`'s no-arg constructor consulting to read these resource entries and return them to the client? Thanks again!

Comment: Take a look at the source code in this package [org.apache.catalina.startup](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-catalina/7.0.0/org/apache/catalina/startup/ContextConfig.java?av=f) It has classes that load the XML config file context.xml(ContextConfig.java) and catalina.properties(CatalinaProperties.java). Tomcat registers those resources as per the [JNDI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/overview/index.html) standards and that's why your blank InitialContext can find it. It's merely adhering to accepted Java naming retrieval specs.